# how to call another method in a method within the same class

Tags: java

This is the code fragment so far, I have tried calling the getCard Method that I coded within the same class but it seems to be giving me errors when I compile

```
@WebService
public class Card {

    @WebMethod
    public int getCard() {
        Random r = new Random();
        int rand = r.nextInt((10) + 1);
        return rand;
    }

    public int getCards() {
        int one;
        one.getCard();
        int two;
        two.getCard();
        //getCard one = new getCard();
        //getCard two = new getCard();
        int three = (one + two);
        return three;
    }
}
```

Comment: `one.getCard();`  ?? where one is a primitive int ?

Comment: getCard() is defined for a Card object not an int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot call `one.getCard()` as `one` is of type int. Also you need not use `new` keyword while calling the method. `new` keyword is used to create new object. Just use

```
one = getCard();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not do `one.getCard()`  because this is how an object calls a method, whereas your one is declared as `int`  which is a primitive type. Remember your getCard simply returning a value that's why you need something to capture the value.

```
int one = getCard();
```

this works. now if you set your getCard method return a String then to capture the String you can use

```
String one = getCard();
```

again capturing the primitive type. Similar concepts works for all primitive type such as `long`, `char` `float` `double` `boolean` etc. Hope that helps.